# Detect red square in image with OpenGL-ES

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, gpu

I need to write a program that will detect a red square in an image. I would like to do this on my GPU using OpenGl-ES. I have no experience with GPU programming, and haven't found the answer through Google so far.
Is it possible to do this using OpenGL? Does OpenGL-ES give access to the whole matrix of pixels as well as their location in the matrix, allowing a program to go through the pixels, and check the color value of each one as well as their locations in the matrix?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Above all, you are confused to call a few terms.  There is 'no matrix of pixels'

If what you meant by that is Convolution, yes, you can put the convolution on Fragment shader to detect edges. However, there is no returning datas, and no way to access each pixel to get the color value. Convolution would work if you just want the shader to draw of square's edge. But if you want to know if a red square exist in the camera frame it must be calculated in CPU not in GPU.